memberOf through FHIRPath in Azure FHIR Service
I would like to use FHIRPath patches to check whether data in my FHIR Service conforms to code systems. I tried to use the memberOf FHIRPath function but received the following error: Invocation of function 'memberOf' failed: Terminology functions in FhirPath are unsupported in the .NET FhirPath engine
I have tried simply using the in keyword and referencing the ValueSet directly, but no results are returned:
Medication.where(code.coding.where(system = 'http://www.whocc.no/atc').code in ValueSet.where(url = 'http://www.whocc.no/atc?vs').expansion.contains.code)

What options does Azure FHIR Service offer to achieve this goal?
